# Economics thought experiment?

Tags: philosophy-of-economics

If an artist paints the mona lisa. Can it be bought (capitalism)?
Should it be distributed to everyone? (Socialism) or
We allow it to inform the value system (like all great art does?)

What is the relation between art and economics?

For example, I as an artist painted something for my mentor. Now can this be bought? (Because it informs the value system. I disagree it can be bought).
Should it be shared by the people (people who discovered their Buddhist freedom? -Discussions on youth - Daimaku Ikeda).
Should it inform the value system?

It's kinda like saying before the renaissance period how much can I buy it for? How does one make an advance: calling it an edge case (based on the will of the people)?

Comment: What exactly is the question here? Also what part of the art? Like the physical object of the mona lisa is a token that can move around so theoretically a system in which every such token can be bought it could be bought as well. Though probably the artist tried to immortalize something, so can that be bought? Can it even be found that easily without understanding the art and being an artist? Also what about copies and replicas, are they protected because the artist took claim of a whole segment of art or is it just about that one token?

Comment: Also what part of the art? Why think physically? Like we get into a conversation so inspiring we both come into agreement of something revolutionary. How is the to be credited for this?

Comment: The issue already occurred: see Andy Wharol.

Comment: I don't know what you mean by "inform the value system"? In general, the economic value of something is equal to what someone is willing to pay. A glass of water in the desert might be pricey. Leaves in the Fall are worthless.

Comment: @ScottRowe things have inherent value. Why? Because we inherently want to live. From that point of view the rest are details imo

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I am not sure why you consider a painting to be any different in economic terms to other outputs of human effort. If you adopt a broad definition of art to encompass music, film, literature and so on, it is a multi-billion dollar industry. Creators invest effort and capital in production, marketing and distribution of artistic artefacts or live performances, and consumers decide whether to pay for them based on their perception of the value offered.

Art can differ from purely commercial production, in that some artists create for the purpose of self-expression or to spread a message or achieve some form of interaction, without any intent to make money from their activities.

The valuation of certain types of art sometimes has no relationship to the costs of production, but is driven instead by other factors, such as the celebrity of the artist. There is also a tradition, in some societies at least, of public funding of art, both in terms of its production and enabling the enjoyment of it. There are parallels there with the subsidy of other goods and services for public consumption, so it is not unique to art.

Comment: The *profession* of artist implies that somebody *pays* for the bodies of art produced/performed, yes.

Comment: Agree. Reproduction affects price. Books got a lot cheaper 500 years ago, but selling many copies cheaply is a better business model than one expensive one. Loss leaders can be discounted or even free, but still improve profitability. Lots of music, TV, movies etc are free now. Assigning economic value becomes complex.